# SOQL Query - Get records where TODAY is between to Date Fields

Tags: soql, query, date

I'm trying to make a query in salesforce that can evaluates Today's date between two dates.

By "between" I mean that the current system date is >= From_Date__c and <= To_Date__c

This is my current query:

```
SELECT Id,From_Date__c,To_Date__c FROM Rebate__c where From_Date__c <= TODAY and To_Date__c >= TODAY
```

if we write above query, its not getting records as we have records on the same date.
please let us know, how to get records on the same date.
example : we want to get the records for from : 28.11.2019 and To :28.11.2019.
the above query showing nothing.

Comment: I guess you might need to switch fields in where clause, is it not working?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This query runs perfectly fine on my instance, and looks identical to yours.

```
SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Start_Date__c <= TODAY AND End_Date__c >= TODAY
```

---

If you have a specific problem, you should [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/195956/edit) your question to include it.